# C++ Best way to have class member which is a pointer (or reference) to another class and can handle both const and non-const situations

Tags: c++, member-pointers, const-pointer, data-member-pointers

Consider the following sample code. It compiles and works as expected. However, if I add "const" to the beginning of the first line of main function, it will not compile, because B class takes a *pointer to A*, and with const being added, we will have a *pointer to **const** A* instead. Templatizing B is an option, but I wonder if there are cleaner/nicer solutions for this. I am open to various suggestions, including moving the B inside A if that would help (B is used by A only).

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class B;

template <typename T>
class A{
  friend class B<T>;

  std::vector<T> data;

public:
  A(int n) {
    data.resize(n); for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      data[i] = static_cast<T>(i);
  }
  B<T> getB(int pos) {return B<T>(this, pos);}
  const B<T> getB(int pos) const {return B<T>(this, pos);}
};

template <typename T>
class B {
    A<T>* pointerToA;
    int pos;
  public:
    B(A<T>* pointerToA_, int pos_) : pointerToA(pointerToA_), pos(pos_) {}
    T& get() const { return pointerToA->data[pos]; }
    T& get() { return pointerToA->data[pos]; }
  };

int main() {
  A<int> a(10); // const A<int> a(10); will not compile!
  int& i = a.getB(3).get();
}
```

Comment: You could use a `std::variant<Outer*, const Outer*>`. Seems bad compared to using a template.

Comment: Or, just an ordinary `union` if you want to avoid a memory overhead of `variant`: https://godbolt.org/z/6af5cz.

Comment: Note that this is not really about nested definitions; that's a distraction. The same problem would occur if `Inner` was defined outside of `Outer`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, You are right. I just thought of my use case. I will edit the description accordingly.

Comment: Well done. The key to debugging is removing distractions.