# If template parameter AA is a templatized class A<T> itself, is it possible to get the template parameter (T) of this templatized class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates, non-type-template-parameter

Consider the code below:

```
template <typename T>
class A{
...
}

template <class U>
class B{
...
}

int main {
B<A<int>> a;
...
}
```

How can I get the template parameter of A (int in this case) inside B, if A<int> is the template parameter for B?
I could parametrize B as follows, but I feel like I am sending an unnecessary piece of information.

```
template <class AA, typename T>
class B { ... }
```

The reason I do not simply use `template <typename T>` for class B is that I have a pointer to class A inside B, and I want to use the template parameter `class AA` to see if that pointer is const or not, hence have the correct type for the member pointer in B.

Comment: You could partially specialize it like `template<typename T> class B<A<T>> { /* whatever */ };`. And there's no harm in your own solution either. Your question is too vague for a more concrete answer.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, thanks for the answer. class B is supposed to always have A<T> as template parameter. It is T that is the real parameter (as well as constness of A<T>).

Comment: So, why not using `template <typename T>
class B{ A<T> X; ...};` ?

Comment: @Damien, Because I have 'A<T>* X' or 'const A<T>* X' depending on whether A is const or not. Assume that A is a very big class and I want to have a pointer to that inside B, but at the same time A might be const or not. I have asked another question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65286216/10755448

Comment: I don't see what it changes. You could have `template <typename T> class B{ A<T> *X; const A<T> *Y; ...}; ...

Comment: @Damien, Perhaps there is something that I do not know or understand here. But let me clarify. I have just X, it points to an A, that A might be const or not, so the type of X depends on the constness of A that it points to. Assume that B is created inside A, and inside A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways, depending of that you might change:

- Quick way, specialize B

  ```
  template <class> class B;

  template <class T>
  class B<A<T>>
  {
      // Use directly T
      //...
  };
  ```
- Add info in `A` directly (as std containers do with `value_type`)

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct A
  {
      using my_type = T;
  };

  // Then in `B<U>`, use `typename U::my_type`
  ```
- Use external traits to extract information from `A` (as `std::iterator_traits`) (that also allows to handle built-in types):

  ```
  template <typename T>
  struct ATrait;

  template <typename T>
  struct ATrait<A<T>>
  {
      using my_type = T;
  };

  // Possibly a generic one
  template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
  struct ATrait<C<T>>
  {
      using my_type = T;
  };

  // Then in `B<U>`, use `typename ATrait<U>::my_type`
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following does what you want:

```
#include<type_traits>
template<class>
class A{};

template<class>
struct get_inner;

template<template<class> class TT, class T>
struct get_inner<TT<T>> {
    using outer = TT<T>;
    using inner = T;
};

template<class TT>
struct B {
    using A = TT;
    using inner = typename get_inner<std::decay_t<A>>::inner;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static_assert(std::is_const_v<typename B<const A<int>>::A>);
        static_assert(!std::is_const_v<typename B<A<int>>::A>);
}
```

Note the `std::decay_t`, it wouldn't work with the `const` parameter directly (hence we cannot just specialize `B` in this way). Maybe `decay_t` is a bit strong but it works^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
template <typename X> class B;

template <template <typename> class XX, typename T>
class B<XX<T>>
{
    // your implementation
};

B<A<int>> a;
```